# consuming country.asmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm trying to add the country web service to a dropdownlist. I have added the web reference and have the discomap and wsdl files.

Here's my code-behind:

```
net.webservicex.www.country ws = new net.webservicex.www.country();
ddlCountry.DataSource = ws.GetCountries();
ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

I tried the above code, but it only displays one character per line in the dropdownlist. I'm not really sure how to do this, this is my first time using web services. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: what kind of object does ws.GetCountries() return?

Comment: i think it's a string. how do i check?

Comment: check the signature for `GetCountries();`

Comment: mousing over shows string country.GetCountries()

Comment: I would think it should return some kind of a collection of string, like `List<sting>` or `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: how should i iterate over it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetCountries() returns XML. You need to parse XML to get the list of countries as a list of strings.

If you have .NET 3.5 or higher, you can do this easily with LINQ to XML.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var service = new net.webservicex.www.country();
            var xml = service.GetCountries();
            var countries = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("Name").Select(arg => arg.Value).ToList();
            countriesDropDownList.DataSource = countries;
            countriesDropDownList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add the dropdownlist selection to the sql database, but when I do that by using ddlCountry.SelectedValue in my insert statement, only the first value in the dropdownlist is showing up in the table. Should I use onselectedindexchanged to somehow store the value? What code should I be using? TIA.